# Number of ways to form an amount with certain coins

Tags: java

I am trying to solve this problem. http://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/coin-change-ii/#

This is the standard coin change problem solvable with dynamic programming. The goal is to find the number of ways to create an amount using an infinite set of coins, where each has a certain value. I have created the following solution :

```
public int change(int amount, int[] coins) {
    // write your code here
    int[] dp = new int[amount + 1];
    dp[0] = 1;


    // for(int coin : coins) {
    //     for(int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
    //         if(i >= coin) dp[i] += dp[i-coin];
    //     }
    // }


    for(int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
        for(int coin : coins) {
            if(i >= coin) dp[i] += dp[i-coin];
        }
    }

    return dp[amount];
}
```

Why does the first for loop give the correct answer, but the second one does not? What am I missing here? Shouldn't the answer be the same? Could you provide a visual to help me "see" why the second for loop is incorrect? 
When the amount = 8 and coins = [2,3,8] the output is 5 when it should be 3 when using the 2nd for loop's technique which is not correct.

Thank you.

Comment: Spend some time in your favourite debugger and the answer will come to you very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the loop that works first:

```
for(int coin : coins) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
         if(i >= coin) dp[i] += dp[i-coin];
     }
}
```

Each iteration of the outer loop takes a coin of one value and finds out the number of ways to reach any value between the coin value and `amount`, adding that coin to the result of the previous iterations.

Considering your `amount = 8` and `coins = [2,3,8]` example:

The array is initialized to

```
index    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
value    1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

which means that without any of the coins, the only amount we can reach is `0`, and we have a single way to reach that amount (0 2s, 0 3s, 0 8s).

Now we find the amounts we can reach with just the coin of value 2:

```
index    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
value    1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

It's not surprising that we can reach any even amount. For each such amount we have a single way to reach that amount (1 2s to reach 2, 2 2s to reach 4, etc...).

Now we find the amounts we can reach with coins of value 2 or 3. We can reach an amount k using a single coin of 3 if we already found ways to reach the amount k-3.

Below I show the number of ways to reach each value between 0 and 8, and specify how many coins of each type are used in each combination.

```
index    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
value    1   0   1   1   1   1   2   1   2

         0x2 -   1x2 0x2 2x2 1x2 3x2 2x2 4x2
         0x3 -   0x3 1x3 0x3 1x3 0x3 1x3 0x3

                                 or      or

                                 0x2     1x2
                                 2x3     3x3
```

Finally, in the last iteration we consider the coin of 8. It can only be used to reach the amount 8, so we get the final result:

```
index    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
value    1   0   1   1   1   1   2   1   3
```

When you swap the loops:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
    for(int coin : coins) {
        if(i >= coin) dp[i] += dp[i-coin];
    }
}
```

you bring the order the coins are added into play. For example, the amount 5 can be reached by either first taking a coin of 2 and then a coin of 3, or by first taking a coin of 3 and then a coin of 5. Therefore the value of `dp[5]` is now 2.

Similarly, `dp[8]` results in `5` since you can take any of the following sequences of coins:

```
2+3+3
3+2+3
3+3+2
2+2+2+2
8
```

The original loop doesn't distinguish between `2+3+3`, `3+2+3` and `3+3+2`. Hence the different output.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int coinChange(int[] coins, int sum) {

        int size = coins.length;
        int[][] arr = new int[size + 1][sum + 1];

        // Applying the recursive solution:
        for(int i = 1; i < size +1; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < sum +1; j++) {
                arr[i][0] = 1;

                if (coins[i - 1] > j) {
                    arr[i][j] = arr[i - 1][j];
                } else
                    arr[i][j] = arr[i - 1][j]+arr[i][j - coins[i - 1]] ;
            }}

        return arr[size][sum];enter code here
```